# How to use an environment variable in a Nuxt.js project for a file that is not injected as plugin?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, environment-variables, nuxt.js

I have a file in my Nuxt.js project that simply resides in the `src` directory. Therefore it is **not** in the convention of a Nuxt project. Therefore I understand that environment variables defined in the `nuxt.config.js` will not appear in the file placed in `src`.

However I'd still like to use environment variables in that mentioned file.
This is how I try to access the environment variable:

```js
const GAMESERVER_URL = process.env.GAMESERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1001'
```

Unfortunately it always falls back to the default value `http://localhost:1001`. I have another file used as Nuxt.js plugin that is referencing the very same environment variable with the exact same statement (above). The *plugin* file works fine and is using the environment variable correctly.

What are my options to also introduce the environment variables to my *standalone* file in the `src` directory?

Comment: A JS file so? Or what kind?

Comment: `src/websocket.ts` that's the file. It's my websocket client class